# How to check all the available nightly builds for a cargo crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I would like to find out under which nightly builds can I compile my code with a specific crate (in this case [`rustc_ast`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_ast/index.html)). I know I can do it using the latest nightly (`rustc 1.51.0-nightly (44e3daf5e 2020-12-31)`), but I have an additional dependency that only compiles on `nightly-2020-10-05` & earlier. However, when I check with that one, I get:

```
26 | extern crate rustc_ast;
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't find crate
```

My end goal would be to find some nightly build which is compatible with both.

Is there a simple tool that allows for listing all available versions for a crate, something like: `cargo versions rustc_ast`? Thanks for help!

Comment: https://crates.io/crates/rustc-ap-rustc_ast/versions

Comment: @IvanC That somewhat helps, although with `rustup override set nightly-2020-09-29` I still get the `can't find crate` error. I am not sure whether the date of publishing the crate corresponds 1:1 with nightly build versions